# Add Virtual Credit/Debit card directly to Apple Wallet

Tags: ios, applepay

I have an app where the users sign up and in the process they take a picture of their Credit/Debit card and fund their account with some balance from that card and with this balance I have created a virtual card. My question is, is there any way I can add this virtual card into Wallet without giving any physical card? I know that it was not possible and we may need to contact Apple directly to get that access, but wanna know if anything new came up in iOS 10 that allows us to do it now. Any help regarding this will be high appreciated.

Thanks,
Rk

Comment: If you are talking about ApplePay, then no. Cards need to be enrolled using the ApplePay process and the card needs to be issued from an issuer that supports ApplePay.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am aware of that thing but was thinking if Apple had opened something in iOS10 through which that is possible now.

Comment: No, they wouldn't  and couldn't do that. There is a great deal of security and specific process involved in enrolling a card for ApplePay

Answer (score 0):

Well yes they would and they have added manual card details input. What’s the diff anyway. Still goes through same verification process and anyone could easily make a card for a camera scan these days if so inclined

Comment: This does not answer the question in original post. Please consider posting this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything that prevents you from adding cards to an Apple Wallet. Looks like there's some existing wrappers out there and you can leverage react-native-wallet for your use-case https://github.com/erikpoort/react-native-wallet

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30391839)